# iOS SDK: No Classes or Resources folder?

Tags: iphone, xcode, ios

I'm developing my first iOS app, and everything I read says that each project should have a Classes and Resources folder.

I've tried creating each type of project (view-based, window-based, etc) and I never have the file structure it seems I should. Please help!

PS: I'm using XCode 4.0.1

Comment: Don't worry about it. Xcode will make the folders for you. Just make your app and see if it runs.

Comment: xcode 4 doesn't actually structure those things automatically like that anymore - you can if you like, but there's no need to.  they way it handles it now is dumps them into one directory, and lets you group them inside xcode as you like

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That was the convention the Xcode 3 templates used, apparently this has changed for the Xcode 4 templates and they are laid out differently.  It doesn't matter, Xcode still knows where everything is.

Comment: Thanks! I was searching for an answer because my media is not showing up in interface builder. I dropped in a png to my project folder in XCode, but it does not exist in interface builder

Comment: If you put it in the same folder with Finder, that doesn't automatically add it to the project.  You need to drag the files into Xcode.  It doesn't matter where they are, as long as they are added to the project.